# Put attributes via XElement_Not as XMLAttribute

Tags: c#, xml, xattribute

Here is my two classes: the class Characteristic and Definition :

```
[DataContract]
    public class Characteristic
    {
        [DataMember]
        public Definition Definition { get; set; }
    }

  [Serializable]
    public class Definition
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public int id;
        [XmlAttribute]
        public stringName;
    }
```

and this is my implementation :

```
     Characteristic lstChars = new Characteristic()
                        {
                            Definition = new Definition()
                            {
                                id = Dimension.ID,
                                name = Dimension.Name
                            }
                        };
```

I get this result:

```
<Characteristic>
  <Definition>
         <id>6</id>
          <name>ACTIVITY</name>
  </Definition>
```

And my objectif is to get this result:

```
<Characteristic>

  <Definition id="6" Name= "ACTIVITY" />
```

Comment: How are you serializing it? Works fine for me

Comment: No i didn't add anything, just I make the Definition class as  [Serializable]
So how can fix this for get my result : <Definition id="6" Name= "ACTIVITY" />   ?
Thanks,

Comment: You do not need the implementation code.  Just using serialization will work.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @jdweng , but I don't understand what is mean : I am not need the implementation ?

Comment: You said "and this is my implementation :".

Comment: yes this implementation is to get the values of ID and the NAME,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to serialize it, you can use the following ways:

To serialize it into a string:

```
string result;

using (var writer = new StringWriter())
{
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(Characteristic)).Serialize(writer, lstChars);
    result = writer.ToString();
}
```

To serialize and store it on a file:

```
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(xmlFilePath))
{
    new XmlSerializer(typeof(Characteristic)).Serialize(writer, lstChars);
}
```